Computing a difficult definite integral in nuclear physics
I've come across a difficult integral:

The context is computing a particular observable in nuclear physics where one imagines that they have a Fermi gas of nucleons and so one has to average this observable over all nucleons in the Fermi sea up to the Fermi momentum.

The integral is:
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{k}p\sqrt{m^{2} + p^{2}} \left[\left((C + \frac{p}{\sqrt{m^2 + p^2}})^{2}\right)^{3/2}\right.
\\& \left.\rule{3.1cm}{0pt}-\left((C - \frac{p}{\sqrt{m^2 + p^2}})^{2}\right)^{3/2}\right]{\rm d}p
\end{align}
I've tried evaluating this with $\tt Mathematica$ but have had no luck. C is always greater than 1, so that the quantities inside the inner most parenthesis are always positive.

If there is no typo then these seem like fairly straightforward $p=m \tan(\theta)$ substitutions.

Apologize,  I simplified the trinomials into perfect squares, but left the ${(()^2)^{3/2}}$ because of the ambiguity of the sign

You can rewrite it as $|\dots|^3$, which exposes why you need to split the integral at the positive solution to $C=\pm p (m^2+p^2)^{-1/2}$ i.e. $p=|mC|/\sqrt{1-C^2}$ if $C \in (-1,1)$ (or otherwise you don't have to do the splitting at all). After doing that splitting (or resolving that it isn't needed), this seems like a typical trigonometric substitution problem, made routine by the substitution $p=m\tan(\theta)$.

C is actually always great than 1, I have added that to the question.

Well in that case there is no sign ambiguity anywhere, and you can just simplify the whole thing.

Assuming $m>0$ and then rationalising the integrand yields
$$
I= \int_0^k p \sqrt{m^2+p^2}\left[\left(c^2-\frac{p^2}{m^2+p^2}\right)^3\right] d p =\int_0^k \frac{p\left(m^2+p^2\right)}{\sqrt{m^2+p^2}}\left(c^2-\frac{p^2}{m^2+p^2}\right)^3 d p
$$
Letting $x=\sqrt{m^2+p^2}$ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I= & \int_m^{\sqrt{m^2+k^2}} x^2\left(C^2-\frac{p^2}{x^2}\right)^3d x \\
= & {\left[\frac{C^6 x^3}{3}-3 C^4 p^2 x-\frac{3 C^2 p^4}{x}+\frac{p^6}{3 x^3}\right]_m^{\sqrt{m^2 +k^2}} } \\
= & \frac{C^6\left(m^2+k^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}-3 C^4 p^2 \sqrt{m^2+k^2}-\frac{3 C^2 p^4}{\sqrt{m^2+k^2}} \\
& +\frac{p^6}{3\left(m^2+k^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{C^6 m^3}{3}+3 C^4 p^2 m +\frac{3 C^2 p^4}{m}-\frac{p^6}{3 m^3}
\end{aligned}
$$
